# How to loop through an array on keyboard event

Tags: javascript

```
let arr = []
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
    arr.push('heart'+arr.length)
})

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 40) { // down
    // alert me with last item in arr
  } 
})


<button>add hearts</button>
```

How can I show an alert with the last item in `arr` when I hit down on my keyboard? And so every time I hit `down arrow` I get the next array in line.

The first time I hit `down` = alert last arr item

The second time I hit `down` = alert before last arr item

...... and so on

https://jsfiddle.net/o8L4qvb3/

Comment: `alert(arr.pop())`?

Comment: indeed :) thaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.pop removes the last element from array and *returns it*

```
    let arr = []

    document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
        arr.push('heart'+arr.length)
      console.log (arr)
    })

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
        if (e.keyCode === 40) { // down
        // alert me with last item in arr
        alert(arr.pop())
      } 
    })
```